# Windows CreateProcess exit not detected

Tags: c, windows, io-redirection

I am attempting to use a separate process to do some work. In the windows version, I launch it with CreateProcess and redirect the stdin/stdout normally (inherited anonymous pipes). The pipes work; however, when the child process exits, the parent hangs on the read call.

How can the parent know the child process has exited? I thought ReadFile was supposed to immediately return a broken pipe error when the child exits.

The windows example code for creating a child process with redirected input and output has the same problem, so I will post it as the MCVE. It is also available at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms682499

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <strsafe.h>

#define BUFSIZE 4096 

HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

HANDLE g_hInputFile = NULL;

void CreateChildProcess(void); 
void WriteToPipe(void); 
void ReadFromPipe(void); 
void ErrorExit(PTSTR); 

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]) 
{ 
   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr; 

   printf("\n->Start of parent execution.\n");

// Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 

   saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
   saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
   saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

// Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 

   if ( ! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0) ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("StdoutRd CreatePipe")); 

// Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.

   if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdout SetHandleInformation")); 

// Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN. 

   if (! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0)) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin CreatePipe")); 

// Ensure the write handle to the pipe for STDIN is not inherited. 

   if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin SetHandleInformation")); 

// Create the child process. 

   CreateChildProcess();

// Get a handle to an input file for the parent. 
// This example assumes a plain text file and uses string output to verify data flow. 

   if (argc == 1) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Please specify an input file.\n")); 

   g_hInputFile = CreateFile(
       argv[1], 
       GENERIC_READ, 
       0, 
       NULL, 
       OPEN_EXISTING, 
       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY, 
       NULL); 

   if ( g_hInputFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateFile")); 

// Write to the pipe that is the standard input for a child process. 
// Data is written to the pipe's buffers, so it is not necessary to wait
// until the child process is running before writing data.

   WriteToPipe(); 
   printf( "\n->Contents of %s written to child STDIN pipe.\n", argv[1]);

// Read from pipe that is the standard output for child process. 

   printf( "\n->Contents of child process STDOUT:\n\n", argv[1]);
   ReadFromPipe(); 

   printf("\n->End of parent execution.\n");

// The remaining open handles are cleaned up when this process terminates. 
// To avoid resource leaks in a larger application, close handles explicitly. 

   return 0; 
} 

void CreateChildProcess()
// Create a child process that uses the previously created pipes for STDIN and STDOUT.
{ 
   TCHAR szCmdline[]=TEXT("child");
   PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo; 
   STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE; 

// Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 

   ZeroMemory( &piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );

// Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
// This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.

   ZeroMemory( &siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
   siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
   siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
   siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
   siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
   siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

// Create the child process. 

   bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL, 
      szCmdline,     // command line 
      NULL,          // process security attributes 
      NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
      TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
      0,             // creation flags 
      NULL,          // use parent's environment 
      NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
      &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
      &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION 

   // If an error occurs, exit the application. 
   if ( ! bSuccess ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateProcess"));
   else 
   {
      // Close handles to the child process and its primary thread.
      // Some applications might keep these handles to monitor the status
      // of the child process, for example. 

      CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
      CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
   }
}

void WriteToPipe(void) 

// Read from a file and write its contents to the pipe for the child's STDIN.
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{ 
   DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 
   CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

   for (;;) 
   { 
      bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hInputFile, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
      if ( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 

      bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
      if ( ! bSuccess ) break; 
   } 

// Close the pipe handle so the child process stops reading. 

   if ( ! CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr) ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("StdInWr CloseHandle")); 
} 

void ReadFromPipe(void) 

// Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
// and write to the parent process's pipe for STDOUT. 
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{ 
   DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 
   CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE]; 
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
   HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

   for (;;) 
   { 
      bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
      if( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 

      bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf, 
                           dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
      if (! bSuccess ) break; 
   } 
} 

void ErrorExit(PTSTR lpszFunction) 

// Format a readable error message, display a message box, 
// and exit from the application.
{ 
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)+lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)+40)*sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(1);
}
```

Here is the child process code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 4096 

int main(void) 
{ 
   CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE]; 
   DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 
   HANDLE hStdin, hStdout; 
   BOOL bSuccess; 

   hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
   hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); 
   if ( 
       (hStdout == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) || 
       (hStdin == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
      ) 
      ExitProcess(1); 

   // Send something to this process's stdout using printf.
   printf("\n ** This is a message from the child process. ** \n");

   // This simple algorithm uses the existence of the pipes to control execution.
   // It relies on the pipe buffers to ensure that no data is lost.
   // Larger applications would use more advanced process control.

   for (;;) 
   { 
   // Read from standard input and stop on error or no data.
      bSuccess = ReadFile(hStdin, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL); 

      if (! bSuccess || dwRead == 0) 
         break; 

   // Write to standard output and stop on error.
      bSuccess = WriteFile(hStdout, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL); 

      if (! bSuccess) 
         break; 
   } 
   return 0;
}
```

Here is the output from execution. The problem is the parent never detects the child exit, so never finishes.

```
->Start of parent execution.

->Contents of E:\Development\test\redirect\Debug/data.txt written to child STDIN
 pipe.

->Contents of child process STDOUT:

+ This is a test of windows pipes.
+ This is only a test.
 ** This is a message from the child process. **
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to make a small code example available to show how you have made the calls?

Comment: it hangs i*on `ReadFromPipe` that is obvious , use threads to read and write to pipes.

Comment: I do not believe threads (or the lack of them) to be the problem.  I have used this same code, or very similar, as the base for an application where I launch a process, then return.  It works.

Comment: This is occuring within a worker thread, handling a request through the webserver. The child can print a message right before returning from main, and I get that, but the ReadFromPipe still blocks the next time through the loop.  If I try GetExitCodeProcess, it gives me the exit code whether or not I have finished reading from the stream, so that cuts off the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought ReadFile was supposed to immediately return a broken pipe error when the child exits.

Not quite.  It returns immediately when the other end of the pipe is closed, which happens as soon as the last handle is closed.

The parent process isn't closing its copy of the handle.  As far as Windows is concerned, another thread in the parent process might be planning to write to that handle, so the ReadFile continues to wait for that to happen.

So after creating the child process, close the handle:

```
CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
```

*PS:* you can explicitly check whether a process has exited by waiting on the process handle.  But using the pipe is usually easier and more efficient.